# Problem with tidyverse can´t update Package/ load it with library()

Tags: r, tidyverse

so I can easily install tidyverse with install.packages("tidyverse"), but whenever I try to load the package with library(), I receive this error message:

> Error: Loading of package oder namespace for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): failed
> namespace ‘cli’ 3.1.1 is already loaded but >= 3.3.0 is required

I have the R Version 4.1.3. which should be pretty new, so I guess there is no need to update RStudio. I can´t figure out what's wrong. I also tried to run the code multiple times in various project files and scripts. Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some libraries within the tidyverse that don't update as cleanly. In this case, it is `cli`. Try installing `cli` separately and see if that works.

Comment: so I just did that, I could easily load `cli` with `library("cli")` but then I tried to load tidyverse again & I got the same error message from above, just this time the failed namespace was `dplyr` . So I tried to load dplyr separately with library("dplyr") & got this error message: >` Attache Paket: ‘dplyr’

the following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

the following objects are masked from: ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Comment: That is not an error. It is a warning. It is simply saying that there are some functions in the base "stats" package that have been overwritten by dplyr. That is expected. It is just information to you as the user. You should be fine.

Comment: When a package is loaded (linked) and you try to update it, R will complain with this error. Close R, restart it without loading `cli`, then try again. If it happens again, restart R (fresh/no-packages again), explicitly `install.packages("cli")`, and report back.

Comment: @adam was right, it worked after I loaded tidyverse again. Thank you! If the same problem occurs I´ll try your way @r2evans! Thank you both for your help!